# ArcMap Imagery Service Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: arcmap, imagery, services

I am using a NAIP service to display aerial imagery. It appears as if only one tile is ever being pulled. I have played with mosaic properties of the service with no success. The tile changes every time I pan the screen, and typically covers one quarter of the screen.

Here is the service I am trying to use:

> Server: https://naip.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services

My co-worker does not encounter this working on Arc GIS Pro (go figure).
I am using ArcMap 10.5.1.

Comment: That url you shared is invalid. It needs "rest" in there: https://naip.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services

Comment: Its also is challenging for credentials.